# Add classes to menu item based on url

Tags: routes, theming

For various reasons, I can not use the Drupal 7 menu system and have to hardcode a special menu. I am trying to add an active class basing on the URL. I was looking at [this page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) and trying the following.

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><span class="icon-search"></span><a href="/search" title="" class="<?php if ( ($path == $_GET['q'] || ($path == '/search') ) ) : print ('active');endif;?>">Search</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-sports"><a href="/sports" title="">sports</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-news"><a href="/news/" title="">news</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-ent"><a href="/entertainment" title="">entertainment</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: As side note, `$base_url` cannot be equal to `$base_url .'/search'`, so the last snippet will surely fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can read URL with out base path using $_GET['q'] ..

```
<?php if ( $_GET['q'] == "search" ) : print ('active'); endif; ?>
```

OR

You can use [current_path](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7) API function which does the same...

Answer (score 1):

**Update**, here is the working formula.
Thanks Anil for pointing me in correct direction. I got this off [this](https://api.drupal.org/comment/43668#comment-43668) comment

```
$path = current_path();
$path_alias = drupal_get_path_alias(current_path());
<?php if ( $path_alias == "search" ) : print ('active'); endif;  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is an exemple on how to add it to a div parent ( )

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {   
 /*
  *      
  * add contextual classes for each main menu sections for styling     purposes  *
  */
 $url_components = explode('/', request_uri());
 if ('en'===$url_components[1])
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'menu-en-section-'.$url_components[2];
 else
    vars['classes_array'][] = 'menu-section-'.$url_components[2];
 };
```